# Python curve_fit choice of bounds and initial condition affect the result

Tags: python, curve-fitting, boundary, model-fitting

I have a data set that is described by two free parameters which I want to determine using `optimalization.curve_fit`. The model is defined as follows

```
def func(x, a, b,):
    return a*x*np.sqrt(1-b*x)
```

And the fitting part as

```
popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(f = func, xdata = x_data, ydata= y_data, p0 
= init_guess, bounds = ([a_min, b_min], [a_max, b_max]))
```

The outcome of the solutions for `a` and `b` depends quite strong on my choice of `init_guess`, i.e. the initial guess and also on the choice of the bounds.
Is there a way the solve this?

Comment: That the choice of the bounds influence the solution is not that surprising, neither is that the initial guesses do. I guess the best way of dealing with it is i) to choose bounds only then when you are really certain about them (e.g. in your example the bounds for `b` should be chosen in such a way the the `sqrt` is defined) and ii) to look at the quality of the fit by plotting, calculating the residuals etc. Adding some data might also help so that people can play a bit... :)

Answer (score 4):

The authors of the Python scipy module have included the Differential Evolution genetic algorithm in scipy's optimization code as the module `scipy.optimize.differential_evolution`. This module can be used to stochastically find initial parameter values for non-linear regression.

Here is example code from [RamanSpectroscopyFit](https://github.com/zunzun/RamanSpectroscopyFit), which uses scipy's genetic algorithm for initial parameter estimation for fitting Raman spectroscopy data:

```
import numpy as np
import pickle # for loading pickled test data
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import warnings

from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution


# Double Lorentzian peak function
# bounds on parameters are set in generate_Initial_Parameters() below
def double_Lorentz(x, a, b, A, w, x_0, A1, w1, x_01):
    return a*x+b+(2*A/np.pi)*(w/(4*(x-x_0)**2 + w**2))+(2*A1/np.pi)*(w1/(4*(x-x_01)**2 + w1**2))


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
# bounds on parameters are set in generate_Initial_Parameters() below
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    return np.sum((yData - double_Lorentz(xData, *parameterTuple)) ** 2)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([-1.0, 1.0]) # parameter bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([maxY/-2.0, maxY/2.0]) # parameter bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, maxY*100.0]) # parameter bounds for A
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, maxY/2.0]) # parameter bounds for w
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # parameter bounds for x_0
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, maxY*100.0]) # parameter bounds for A1
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, maxY/2.0]) # parameter bounds for w1
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # parameter bounds for x_01

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x



# load the pickled test data from original Raman spectroscopy
data = pickle.load(open('data.pkl', 'rb'))
xData = data[0]
yData = data[1]

# generate initial parameter values
initialParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, niepewnosci = curve_fit(double_Lorentz, xData, yData, initialParameters)

# create values for display of fitted peak function
a, b, A, w, x_0, A1, w1, x_01 = fittedParameters
y_fit = double_Lorentz(xData, a, b, A, w, x_0, A1, w1, x_01)

plt.plot(xData, yData) # plot the raw data
plt.plot(xData, y_fit) # plot the equation using the fitted parameters
plt.show()

print(fittedParameters)
```