# How do I use scipy optimize curve fit with panda df

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

This is my first post here, I've spent hours looking for this answer but I can't seem to figure this out. I've used pandas to pass a .csv to a np matrix. From there I tried to apply a simple curve fit but the output I am getting is consistently wrong. the code will plot wrong fit, and will not plot the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

df = pd.read_csv("Results.csv")
xdata = df['Frame'].as_matrix()
ydata = df['Area'].as_matrix()

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return (a*np.sin(b*x))+(c * np.exp(x))
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)

plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r-',
        label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f, c=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)

plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'g--',
          label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f, c=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This is what the data looks like:
[image: This is what the data looks like]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data file?

Comment: The tricky part about fitting is to find good starting values. If no starting values are given, `curve_fit` will assume them to be all one, `a=b=c=1`. I suppose in your case those are too far away from the actual best fit, such that the fit hangs in a local optimum. Instead start with a `p0` vector of more useful values, i.e. closer to what you would expect.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is absolutely correct. I would like to provide an example of using scipy's Differential Evolution genetic algorithm module to generate initial parameter estimates, which is why I requested a link to the data file.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Maybe it would be better to point OP to a previous answer that shows this (possibly also closing as duplicate), because it doesn't help much if good answers are spread all over different questions.

Comment: @JamesPhillips  Here is a link to the data file.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O_8ymmMdibRttE_Xg3NPVdHQjnxTEp7K/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  Would you say this type of code would work to find the initial bounds? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652776/python-curve-fit-choice-of-bounds-and-initial-condition-affect-the-result/44653860#44653860

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest that example has the basic idea, but the bounds used in that example will probably not work for this problem - which is why I wanted to supply an example with known working bounds for the genetic algorithm. So closing as duplicate seems unwise for this reason.

Comment: @JamesPhillips thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @JamesPhillips So why not edit that answer with an explanation of how to adapt it for other cases (like this one)?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest because no such explanation would be suitable to the majority of cases. Consider this case, where ginormous numbers like exp(1000) are producing math overflow errors - you cannot adapt your way around an incorrect model.

Answer (score 3):

Your model contains "exp(x)" and the data file contains x values of 1000, and this is giving math overflow errors no matter the starting values - the optimizer cannot find a way out of that problem, and you must change the equation to fit this data set. I can suggest other equations, but this data set cannot be fit to the posted equation.

**EDIT**: Per your comment on dividing by 100, here is code using scipy's Differential Evolution genetic algorithm module to find initial parameter estimates, which uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space - that algorithm requires bounds within which to search, and ranges on parameters are much easier to find than exact initial parameter values. Here I tried a few ranges and got what is probably the best fit you can get here from what I can see.

[image: plot]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings


df = pd.read_csv("Results.csv")
xData = df['Frame'].as_matrix() / 100.0
yData = df['Area'].as_matrix()

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return (a*numpy.sin(b*x))+(c * numpy.exp(x))


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, 100.0]) # search bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, 1.0]) # search bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, 1.0]) # search bounds for c

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# now call curve_fit without passing bounds from the genetic algorithm,
# just in case the best fit parameters are aoutside those bounds
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: if I divided the x values by 100 would it rectify the problem?