# Why slightly changing the function caused so much difference in exponential curve fitting in scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

With the curve_fit function in scipy, I got some very werid result. A slight change in my function will make it better. But I don't know why.
This is the code doens't work:

```
def func(x, A1, t1, y0):
    return A1 * np.exp(x/t1) + y0

x_data = np.array(data['tau']) 
y_data = np.array(data['magnitude'])

p0 = [1000, 4, 0] 
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x_data, y_data, p0)
print(popt)

y_fited = func(x_data, *popt)

plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'b-', label='data') 
plt.plot(x_data, y_fited, 'r-', label='fited')
```

The output plot is like this:

[image]

And after I changed the t1 of func from dividing to multiplication, everything seems better.

```
def func(x, A1, t1, y0):
    return A1 * np.exp(x*t1) + y0
```

[image]

Why is this happenning? I can't understand why my first func can't work well, it is not a linear function, which I borrow it from Origin's exponential fitting tool. Thanks in advance!

Here is my x_data:

> [4.9063e-03 4.5800e-03 4.2538e-03 3.9275e-03 3.6012e-03 3.2750e-03
> 2.9487e-03 2.6224e-03 2.2961e-03 1.9699e-03 1.6436e-03 1.3173e-03
> 9.9107e-04 6.6480e-04 3.3853e-04 1.2266e-05]

and y_data:

> [1038.3   921.93  865.19  878.07 1141.9  1043.3  1167.2  1030.5
> 1174.8
> 1331.5  1549.7  1379.8  2134.8  1992.5  2218.8  2505.7 ]

Comment: And I think this is a convex problem, so the initialization is not necessary and the result will just converged to the global minima, is that right?

Comment: If you try `p0=[100, 1, 0]`, you'd see the 2 formulas converge to very similat curves. I think it's a convergence problem especially as the exponents are very small it can take a while to converge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here. Clearly it is a non-linear fit, so there is always the possibility of local minima. Obviously one is found here. The question then is: why? One has to see what the underlying algorithm is doing. Just looking at the `t1` we see that if we would start with `t1=1` both versions would give the same answer. Now the data clearly shows that this is decay, so the result should be negative. The case of `...* t1` hence, needs to get smaller and get negative. This is controlled by the gradient of the local error. Now it is likely that the `.../ t1` case also wants to go in directions of smaller factors, but this means increasing `t1`, it will, therefore, go in the wrong direction. If One prints the values of `t1` throughout the fitting process, one can observe this behavior. Actually at some point it overcomes the "barrier" to negative numbers. However, at that point, the other parameters have already such abnormal values that it goes back to positive.

In detail it depends on the starting parameters and `[5000,1,0]` would work.

At the end I think that **this example is a great lesson** on how to prepare your fit function:

- Try to get the sign correct i.e. `exp( -x * t1 )` would have been better, as it is obviously decay
- if a parameter may chande sign, take care that nothing diverges if the parameter becomes zero. This is somewhat what happened here.
- If possible rescale such that all parameters on the scale of `1`. This to some extend equivalent to providing good starting values. Here a fit-function like  `1000 * a * exp( -1000 * t * x ) + 1000 * c` would converge fast without providing starting values.

Comment: Thank your for your nice explaination. I have different data every day, and are there any simple way to get rid of setting the initial value everytime? Any idea or trick to set the initial value automatically?

Comment: @teruun Well, that depends a bit on how different your "different" is. There is the possibility to use [differential evolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44653860/803359) for parameter estimation. You may also use the solution given by JJacquelin. I've seen it before and luckily my French is good enough to read the linked content. I think it is a nice and clever solution. Depending on the fit function not always straight forward, though. And the answer given here is definitively not self-explaining.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know french at all. I will try this evolution method.

Answer (score 0):

The method of fitting that you used is an iterative method starting from "guessed" initial values for the parameters. Probably the trouble comes from the initial values of the parameters. If they are too far from the correct values the convergence of the iterative process might fails or be too slow or unstable.

This can be avoid if one use a non-iterative method which doesn't requires "guessed" initial values. Such kind of method is explained in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

The calculus which is very simple is shown below :

[image]

[image]

NOTE :

You can use the approximate values of parameters found above as initial values in your softwares and check that they will correctly compute the optimized values of parameters.